# HSQLDB: case sensitive table names

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, hsqldb

I have the following jpa/hibernate/hsqldb configuration:

- JPA `ddl-auto: create-drop`
- Hibernate entities have no `@Table` annotation and created with `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`. So, `PersonalData` entity table name is `personal_data`. Hibernate creates them due to running the application
- `hsql` DB URL is `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb;sql.syntax_pgs=true`

My problem is when I try to select due spring repositories with the hsql there is the error about non-existing `PERSONAL_DATA` table.

I found that this is SQL notation to use CASE_SENSETIVE tables and hqsl follows that. To resolve that developers offer quote table names in sql.

So, I have 2 unlikely ideas

- Add `@Table` annotation to entities.
- Override `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`

Is there a way to use a simple property?